# Assign Users to roles/groups in Azure Active Directory and replicate to local machine

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm currently migrating my 3 devices and users over to Azure Active Directory.  I did NOT have a local Active Directory previously.

2 out of my 3 users are in a Developer role and need local administrator privileges on the machine. Typically I'd log into the machine and assign the user to the "Administrators" role but I'd like to be able to do this without needing to log in.

Can this be done via Azure Active Directory or do I need to log into the machine to make the change?  Or is there a Group Policy I can create in Azure?

I've Googled my issue several times in different ways but the results come up with how to assign roles to users in Azure Active Directory (and nothing about the roles on a local machine) and how to assign Global Admin rights to Azure users (not related to Active Directory).

Comment: Azure AD does not have group policies by itself :) Have a look at AAD DS, it does support a bunch of the things that traditional AD does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-features

Comment: @juunas thanks for that link, it looks like that is exactly what I needed! Sure would be nice if there was some documentation that linked what on-premise is to Azure and all the individual services you need.